# token (deployed by other crowdsale) not showing up on Etherscan

Tags: myetherwallet, etherscan

I have a crowdsale that creates a token. The crowdsale [shows up on Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf45772f7f459209e398193c80c453807255361e0) and can also be used on MyEtherWallet. I read the token address which gets created by the crowdsale constructor via MEW but it is [not visible on Etherscan](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xad819c06a0ee792a9f16cbc5b4acb33fc4a7e4b5)<del>and does also not show any values when interfacing via MEW</del>. I was quite sure that I did not make a mistake here, so I checked in my browser console using Metamask:

```
> function cb(e,r){console.log(e,r);}
> web3.eth.getCode('0xad819c06a0ee792a9f16cbc5b4acb33fc4a7e4b5', cb) // shows code so it worked!
```

also trying to read some properties works well:

```
> let tokn = web3.eth.contract(tokenAbi).at(tokenAddress)
> function cb(e,r){console.log(e,r);}
> tokn.owner(cb)
null "0xf45772f7f459209e398193c80c453807255361e0"
```

Is this a bug in <del>MyEtherWallet and</del> Etherscan?

(also posted on https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/MyEtherWallet/issues/926)

EDIT:

I got the token address via MEW: Use the contract address of the crowdsale `0xf45772F7f459209E398193C80C453807255361e0` and this snippet is all we need as ABI:

```
[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"token","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

Then in MEW go on the "Contract" tab, paste address and ABI given above. Reading the only function `token` returns the token address 0xad819c06a0ee792a9f16cbc5b4acb33fc4a7e4b5.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in etherscan, you should try to report it so they fix it.

Comment: I did report it. By now I can read values in MEW so that is not an issue anymore.